# How I can open pgadmin4 in fedora 36?

Tags: postgresql, fedora, pgadmin-4

Good evening people, I am trying to install pgadmin4 on fedora 36, I followed all the steps in the [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-rpm/) and pgadmin4 and its dependencies were installed correctly but I do not know how to start it, or open it and it does not let me configure it on the web because I do not create the directory described in the final step to configure the web version.

Comment: Would you give the details of when you ran `sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it installing pgadmin4 from linux-pachages

> https://linux-packages.com/fedora-36/package/pgadmin4-qtx86-64

Comment: Aren't those instructions to just install it from the Fedora repo?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same instructions but mistakenly changing "yum" to "dnf" out of force of habit. I found I got an install out of it which seemed OK at a glance, but it was just documentation and not an executable, and there was no shortcut added to run pgAdmin. Perhaps you might have inadvertently done something similar? After uninstalling, I tried again using "yum" exactly as documented and the latest executable installed without any issue. So the steps to install that would work for me were as follows. (Desktop version in my case.)

```
sudo rpm -e pgadmin4-fedora-repo
sudo rpm -i https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/yum/pgadmin4-fedora-repo-2-1.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install pgadmin4-desktop
```

The QT workaround also mentioned as an answer worked for me, but I wanted to avoid that since it is an earlier release (6.9) than the current 6.11, isn't officially supported and fires a warning about that every time on start up saying some functionality may be missing, which is not good for clients to see potentially in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - couldn't open it after installing. You have to install `pgadmin4-desktop` not `pgadmin4`.

Comment: Please explain what additional insight this contributes beyond already existing answers.

Comment: Yes the top answer mentions it but goes on about many things. This is clear, install `pgadmin4-desktop`.

Comment: Note that an answer with "this is the solution" but without any explanation is rarely seen as helpful on StackOverflow. And the impression "just copies core solution from upvoted answer" is often stronger. Leaving out an explanation when focussing on the solution is hence unlikely a good strategy. Copying the explanation however would give an even worse impression. The best thing you can do is add your own explanation, with an insightfully different approach. - Or delete this post.

Comment: Suggesting _pgadmin4**-desktop**_ instead of _pgadmin4_ sounds like a valid answer on its own to me -- the other answers mainly point in other directions.